# How to enforce security in Oracle dump ORA-39327

Tags: oracle, security, encryption

In my scenario the Oracle database (19c) is under Oracle Vault and a user has been given special rights to perform the expdp operation.

My issue is that when the task is executed, the resulting dump is not encrypted:

> ORA-39327: Oracle Database Vault data is being stored unencrypted in dump file set

I know it is possible to specify a password to encrypt the dump file set, but the parameter is optional. Oracle Vault should stop a DBA from reading the data, but how do I prevent a DBA to just to a expdp and then to import the data in clear form?

I tried to execute the expdp without the special rights requested by Vault and the operation failed as those rights are mandatory.

I thought about creating a user with only enough rights for doing a dump, but then that user will be able to import the result in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be the following:

1. Create an PL/SQL export procedure using the [Datapump API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/using-oracle_datapump-api.html) (DBMS_DATAPUMP). Place it in a schema that has privileges to perform the export, but to which DBAs cannot log in (or at least that would create critical  audit records if they altered things to try logging in).
2. Using the API, you can enforce the use of encryption and password protection.
3. Make sure the directory used by the export is to a part of the server to which untrusted users (like DBAs, apparently) don't have access.

In this way you could potentially allow access to this procedure, rather than to the unfiltered command line export utility.

Similarly, you could also consider a custom shell script or some such to prompt for details like the password so that it isn't hard-coded, that would construct the proper expdp command for execution. As with the stored procedure, the script should run from and the dump file generated in a location only accessible by trusted individuals.

Comment: thank you, I'll try this approach. In Vault I should be able to have only a specific group of users able to access procedures (excluding the dba too) so this solution should cover my need. I'll let you know the results.